# How can I highlight words in a word search puzzle?

Tags: unity, 3d

For days I am struggling to implement the highlighting functionality in game as there is not much tutorial also for this. I did how ever make the cell of the grid change the material color but it looks ugly that's why I prefer to choose this method (see pic).

How can I implement a highlighting method that will work the same on [link](https://www.ducksters.com/games/word_search/us_geography.php).

---

[image]

---

My try:

```
 private bool first_sel = false;
    private void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out pressed)) {
                if (pressed.transform.tag == "cell") {
                    if (!first_sel) {
                        GameObject sel = Instantiate(sel_cell, new Vector3(pressed.transform.position.x,
                            pressed.transform.position.y, pressed.transform.position.z - 0.55f), Quaternion.identity);
                    }


                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like something you could do with a [9-slice sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html) appropriately sized & rotated. Have you tried this approach? Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: No. But I did manage to make something like that I used gameobject but I have problem making the highlight stretch.

Comment: Can you update your question to detail this problem?

Comment: @DMGregory Done.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the [line render](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) with a transparent material and a slight offset on the Z axis so it doesn't clip with your board.

```
public float DistanceFromBoard;

private bool mouseDownOnLastFrame = false;
private GameObject startingCell;
private GameObject hoveredCell;
private Vector3 mouseWorldPosition;
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

private void Awake()
{
    lineRenderer = GetComponent();
    lineRenderer.enabled = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        HandleDrag();
    }
    else if(mouseDownOnLastFrame) 
    {
        FinishHighlight();
    }
}

private void HandleDrag()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

    mouseDownOnLastFrame = true;

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) 
    {
        currentCell = hit.collider.gameObject;
        mouseWorldPosition = hit.point;

        if (startingCell != null && go.tag == "cell") // instead of using a tag here I would add the cells to a layer and use a layermask
        {
            startingCell = go;
            lineRenderer.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    lineRenderer.positions[0] = startingCell.transform.position - new Vector3(0f, 0, DistanceFromBoard);
    lineRenderer.positions[1] = hoveredCell.transform.position - new Vector3(0f, 0, DistanceFromBoard);
}

private void FinishHighlight()
{
    startingCell = null;
    lineRenderer.enabled = false;

    // here you might want to validate the highighted word and save the word to a collection of found words.

    // You're also going to want to copy this line renderer's positons and copy them to a new gameobject.
    // this is because we cannot only use one line to highlight all the words
}
```

Also remember to add a line renderer component to your gameobject and give it 2 blank positions.

As for the material, create a new material using the standard shader but change it from "opaque" to "transparent" and lower the alpha.